# C++ lightweight configuration library

Tags: c++, configuration-files

I'm looking for a cross-platform C++ lighweight configuration library with non restrictive licence. I need something more complex than standard properties file with sections, but I don't want to use XML (too much writing :-)).

I would like to write configuration this way:

```
render = 
{
    window = 
    {
        width = 800,
        height = 600
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/). I looks good, but it uses exceptions for error reporting...

Comment: I also think that libconfig is pretty nice. There are a few issues that I have with the C++ API and there doesn't appear to be an implementation for Java (which means only C/C++ applications can read the config files), but for now it's still my go-to config library.

Comment: [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) appears to be dead. The manual pages and download link all go to an unconfigured WordPress site.

Comment: although Google turned up https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig which is still active

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's boost's [property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/property_tree.html). The [license](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html) allows commercial use.

Your example:

```
ptree pt;
pt.put("render.window.width", 800);
pt.put("render.window.height", 600);
```

This can e.g. be exported to JSON

```
write_json("my_config.json", pt);
```

which will then look like

```
{
  "render":
  {
    "window":
    {
      "width": 800;
      "height": 600;
    }
  }
}
```

The same way you can export to XML, INI and INFO.

Comment: In my experience .. Boost is far from lightweight library, but I will look at it, because it looks promising

Comment: @hubrobin: You don't need the entire Boost library to make this work, IIRC. Boost has a tool called [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) designed specifically to extract individual libraries.

Comment: Avoid boost at all costs.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and write your configuration files in `Json`, which has a very similar syntax to the one you like:

```
// Configuration options
{
    // Default encoding for text
    "encoding" : "UTF-8",

    // Plug-ins loaded at start-up
    "plug-ins" : [
        "python",
        "c++",
        "ruby"
        ],

    // Tab indent size
    "indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space": true }
}
```

Is under the `MIT License` so it's very permissive.

Comment: Since this answer was written, [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) has become a very popular JSON library for C++ and is worth a look as well.

Comment: The above isn't standard JSON, as JSON does not allow for comments.